# How to replace DataGridViewRow in DataGridView (under VirtualMode) in Windows Form?

Tags: c#, .net, winforms, datagridview

I have `DataGridView` control used in Windows Form. The `DataGridView` is in virtual mode.

Now, there is a requirement to change the usual row that is generated by `DataGridView` when you set the `RowCount` property.

By setting the `RowCount` property, the `DataGridView` would generate default empty `DataGridViewRow`.

Understood that under `VirtualMode` the `DataGridView` would trigger event `CellValueNeeded`. I have tried to change the row in that event.

```
dataGridView.Rows.Insert(e.RowIndex, new GroupCustomRow());
```

> GroupCustomRow is a custom class inherited from DataGridViewRow.

However, I encountered this problem:

> Operation is not valid because it results in a reentrant call to the
>   SetCurrentCellAddressCore

So, is it possible to use `DataGridView` in `VirtualMode` and have custom row painted?

Thanks for your attention.

Best Regards,

Hatjhie

Answer (score 0):

You can customize your rows in the `DataGridView`'s `RowsAdded` event.